# Command line to combine images in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I have two sets of images in a folder. E.g.

```
Bottom1.png
Bottom2.png
Bottom3.png
```

and

```
Top1.png
Top2.png
Top3.png
```

The top (partially opaque 32-bit) ones need to be layered on top of the bottom (24-bit) images. What command line could I use to accomplish this in Windows? Thanks.

[edit]

Here's the correct solution:

```
convert "bottom00.png" "top00.png" -composite "output00.png"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646035/imagemagick-composite-overlay-opacity

Comment: There's extra stuff in that answer, and the answer is for Linux not Windows.